# Using HttpClient loopback from a Windows Store Unit Test DLL

Tags: c#, .net, testing, httpclient

I have a Windows 8 app that I'm trying to write integration tests for. The app uses a DLL (also ours) that itself uses System.Net.Http.HttpClient internally to connect to a server. If I run the app standalone the the connection works.

I have add an MSTest project to the solution (StoreApps..WindowsApp..TestLibrary) and this project references the library that contains the HttpClient code that I'm trying to test. In the test app when I try and call the library the HttpClient connection times out.

My understanding is that this is happening because the code needs access to the loopback address.

Is there a way around this? Either giving the test code access to the loopback? faking the loopback? or could I use a different project type for the test DLL. As the DLL I want to test is built as a Windows 8 DLL then I need a test project that can reference that.

I guess another option would be to move the server out to a different IP address, don't want to do that  if I can avoid it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13360547/120599

Basically I needed to register an exemption for the app so that it could use the loopback address. The easiest way to do this (it seems) is to debug a test and put a breakpoint in the test code; run Fiddler and use it to list the Windows 8 exemptions, then add the DLL as an exemption. Now life is good